# How to see error when data is not inserting in database table after commenting error_reporting(0) function also

Tags: php, html

how to see what is the actual problem if we enter the data through a form in a textbox to insert in the database table, but there is not displayed any error 
after commenting on the  error reporting(0) also

code for database:

```
<?php
include('connection_temp.inc.php');
include('functions.inc.php');
?>
<?php
sm_registerglobal('MEMBER_ACCOUNT_INFO_ID', 'FIRST_NAME', 'LAST_NAME', 'EMAIL_ID', 'PHONE_NO', 'STATES_ID', 'CITIES_ID', 'PASS', 'LOCALITY');

    $tbl_registrations = array(
                                'FIRST_NAME' => $FIRST_NAME,
                                'LAST_NAME' => $LAST_NAME,                              
                                'STATES_ID' => $STATES_ID,
                                'CITIES_ID' => $CITIES_ID,
                                'EMAIL_ID' => $EMAIL_ID,
                                'PHONE_NO' => $PHONE_NO,
                                'PASS' => $PASS,
                                'LOCALITY' => $LOCALITY,
                                );

    /*$tbl_member_account_info = array(                                                         
                                'FIRST_NAME' => 'ssk',
                                'LAST_NAME' => 'sss',                               
                                'STATES_ID' => '6',
                                'CITIES_ID' => '12',
                                'EMAIL_ID' => 'asd@w.com',
                                'PHONE_NO' => '3324234',
                                'PASS' => '123',
                                'LOCALITY' => 'abad',
                                );*/

    //$registrations_id = insert($con, "tbl_registrations", $tbl_registrations);
    $member_account_info_id = insert($con, "tbl_member_account_info", $tbl_member_account_info);
    //echo $member_account_info_id;
?>
```

Comment: here is my code for database :

Comment: Have you looked in the error logs?

Answer (score 0):

Error reporting must be set as error_reporting(E_ALL) to see all the errors. if you set error_reporting(0) no error will be displayed as it is used to hide all the error generally in production mode. 
And remove the comma in the end as you are passing the array that comma should not be there, and check the $con variable once whether you have properly declared the database connection or not, if the problem is still not resolved check the error by setting the error_reporting(E_ALL) and debug and check whether any error appears in the console.

Comment: still it is not giving error but when , I pass values as commented in the question  the value is  inserted in the database.On other side your suggestion does not give any kind of error and the value is not inserting in the table

Comment: their might be error while inserting the values into the database and you might be missing out a value, can you try INSERT INTO ("database fields") VALUES ("your defined variables or values")  format.

Answer (score 0):

Do not add comma with last element in array. try below code

```
<?php
include('connection_temp.inc.php');
include('functions.inc.php');
?>
<?php
sm_registerglobal('MEMBER_ACCOUNT_INFO_ID', 'FIRST_NAME', 'LAST_NAME', 'EMAIL_ID', 'PHONE_NO', 'STATES_ID', 'CITIES_ID', 'PASS', 'LOCALITY');

    $tbl_registrations = array(
                                'FIRST_NAME' => $FIRST_NAME,
                                'LAST_NAME' => $LAST_NAME,                              
                                'STATES_ID' => $STATES_ID,
                                'CITIES_ID' => $CITIES_ID,
                                'EMAIL_ID' => $EMAIL_ID,
                                'PHONE_NO' => $PHONE_NO,
                                'PASS' => $PASS,
                                'LOCALITY' => $LOCALITY
                                );

    /*$tbl_member_account_info = array(                                                         
                                'FIRST_NAME' => 'ssk',
                                'LAST_NAME' => 'sss',                               
                                'STATES_ID' => '6',
                                'CITIES_ID' => '12',
                                'EMAIL_ID' => 'asd@w.com',
                                'PHONE_NO' => '3324234',
                                'PASS' => '123',
                                'LOCALITY' => 'abad',
                                );*/

    //$registrations_id = insert($con, "tbl_registrations", $tbl_registrations);
    $member_account_info_id = insert($con, "tbl_member_account_info", $tbl_member_account_info);
    //echo $member_account_info_id;
?>
```